# Still problems with fixed known issue regarding hyperlinks in a dashboard graph: _HL_ENCODED_

Tags: lightning, formula, dashboard, hyperlink

I am trying to use a formula with a hyperlink in a dashboard, but it is displayed incorrectly:

[image]

This is a known bug, which Salesforce has fixed not [once](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eNf6AAE), but [twice](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4QIAA0).

But as you can see, to me it doesn't seem like it's fixed. This is the formula that I am using:

```
HYPERLINK("/lightning/r/" & Id & "/view", Accountnummer_AX__c & " - " & Name, "_self")
```

So, it is my error or Salesforce's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to point to Salesforce. Even though you found those past fixed known issues, Winter '21 also seemed to have this issue pop up again in other areas which is why I suspect it's related to it.

1. It plagued [related lists](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001q7LhQAI) (which they fixed before general
   release).
2. They currently have one scheduled to be fixed related to [service
   reports](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000oRWrQAM&title=formula-field-hyperlink-is-shown-as-html-code-in-service-reports).
3. And the following, when a [formula field references another
   formula](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YnRGQA0) is not yet fixed.